# Transferring variables with object reference. With or without &?

Tags: c++, reference

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class class1
{
public:int number = 2;
};

class class2
{
public:
    void method(class1 &obj)
    {
        obj.number;
        std::cout << obj.number;

    }
};

int main()
{
    class1 c1;
    class2 c2;
    c2.method(c1);
}
```

What is the difference between running the `void method(class1 &obj)` with or without `&`?
Does it change use of memory?

I've heard it's nice to use `&` so you don't get a `NullReferenceException`.
I can still access the variable without `&`, so should i use & in this dumb example?

Comment: Have you read any good C++ book? Have your learned how actual parameters are passed to functions and what is reference in C++?

Comment: C++ doesn’t have a “NullReferenceException”. Wherever source you’re learning C++ from, consider getting a good textbook instead.

Comment: @S.M. I've read some java, but not C++ books. Got a recommendation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Sneftel Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it very simple,
Pass by value means the actual value is passed on. Thus you need to copy this value to a variable to use it.

```cpp
void method(class1 obj)
```

Pass by reference means a number (called an address) is passed on which defines where the value is stored.
The address is passed and then no copy is done and the actual object is modified.

```
void method(class1 &obj)
```

Pass-by-references is considered to be more efficient than pass-by-value, because it does not copy the arguments to a new variable of the same type (as it uses the actual object).

Also beware as pass-by-value does not modify the real object (only the copy). A great example to look at for instance is the ̀swap two variables`
as follows:

```cpp
void swap(int a, int b)
{
   int t;

   t  = b;
   b = a;
   a = t;
}
```

If you call by value in a `main` function using `swap(x,y)̀, the inital value (before the call) and the final value (after the call) does not swap.

However, if you define the function instead by reference `void swap(int& a, int& b)` (nothing changes in the body of the function), you will see that calling `swap(x,y)`, will indeed swap the two variables as the operation.

Comment: Thanks, my dad taught me this 15 minutes ago actually.

Comment: The point you made about swap was interesting!